# How to get text flush to top/bottom of a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, markup, w3c

I have a table cell with text in it but how can I make the text flush to the top or bottom of the cell (with no padding above it)? I've tried vertical-align, but it's still not quite to the top 'edge'.

My code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="foo">3.2325</td>
        <td class="bar">4.5931</td>
    </tr>
</table>

table {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
}
.foo {
    font: bold 30px arial;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.bar {
    font: normal 16px arial;
}
```

JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/KznxN/2/

Comment: You can adjust the `line-height` property.

Comment: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KznxN/3/)

Comment: Like that http://jsfiddle.net/KznxN/5/ ?
(But I have no idea WHY that works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on whether you wish more above or below, you adjust the "line-height" depending

example:

```
. {foo
     font: bold 30px arial;
     border-right: 1px solid black;
     vertical-align: top;
     line-height: 24px;
}
```

But beware, it would be better fix the height size of your cell